# Excel displays incorrect cell data, disappears

Tags: excel

Data in my spreadsheet seems to be stored correctly but is displaying wrong.

Each row is displayed in the subsequent row. Row 1 data is not displayed. Row 2 data is displayed in row 1. Row 3 data is displayed in row 2, and so on. If a cell in Row 2 is double-clicked, the correct cell contents are displayed in the formula bar, while the cell contents being displayed disappear.

Also, all text appears to be vertically aligned along the top inside the cells, even though this option isn't chosen. (text appears shifted to the top of each cell)

Sorry if this seems confusing, I appreciate the help. Below is a picture of what all the text looks like, and an example of the cell/formula bar displaying different contents

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I edited my post above, sorry for the confusion

Comment: This is very weird indeed. Either there is some memory problem. In that case, just restart your Excel application (close all Excel files in order to be sure the program is completely stopped), or there is a macro, causing this behaviour. Just try to restart Excel and see how it goes.

Comment: Closing all my workbooks, and then reopening this one fixed the issue. I am running some macros, but nothing that should be affecting things like this? As far as cell formatting goes, this is all I have:                                                                            ('Sheet2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
Sheet2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearFormats
Sheet2.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
Sheet2.Cells.Font.Size = 11')

Answer (score 0):

The modification of the font size can indeed cause such an issue, although normally font size modification also causes row heigth update.

I would advise you to do following modifications to your macro:
Currently:

```
Sheet2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
Sheet2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearFormats 
Sheet2.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri" 
Sheet2.Cells.Font.Size = 11
```

Change it into:

```
Sheet2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
Sheet2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearFormats
```

As you see, just drop the formatting specification.